# Get Count For Each Distinct Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get the count for each distinct value for a certain field?

```
for name in (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table)
  SELECT COUNT name FROM table
```

without using a cursor that is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `COUNT()` -- an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name
```